# Firebase tableView - Update on loop of observeEvent

Tags: ios, asynchronous, firebase

I have the following problem,
I am getting a list of trend posts (Structs) and then populate a tableview with the following code :

```
  func mainLoad() {
    self.posts.removeAll()
    let trendsRef = Firebase(url: "https://XXXXXXXXfirebaseio.com/TRENDS")

    trendsRef.queryOrderedByChild("firedate").queryLimitedToLast(20).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        self.posts.removeAll()
        var newItems = [getTrend]()
        var i: UInt = 0

        for item in snapshot.children {
            i = i + 1
            let postitem = getTrend(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(postitem)

            if i == snapshot.childrenCount {

                self.hookedUsernames = ["TRENDS"]
                self.trends = newItems
                //newItems.removeAll()
                self.updateTrendPage()
            }

        }
    })
}


func updateTrendPage(){
    var i = 0
    for item in self.trends {

        let Postref = Firebase(url: "https://XXXXXXXfirebaseio.com/POSTS/" + item.useruid + "/" + item.key)
        Postref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in

            i = i + 1
            let mytrendPost : getitems = getitems(snapshot: snap)
            self.posts.append(mytrendPost)
            if i == self.trends.count {
                i = 0
                self.posts = self.posts.reverse()
                self.data = [self.posts]
                self.contentTableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }

}
```

The problem is if I update one of the trend post, the callback function will update the data correctly but I can t seem to find a way to "reload the cell" of even reload the tableView (wich is heavy nevertheless). Is there a way to, maybe index the tableview and just reload part of it Only in case of a call back ? (hum I don t know how to explain this in a better way)

Comment: Just a thought: why not add a .childChanged observer? That will notify your app of which specific child changed. Read in the snapshot, update the index in the newItems array and then do a tableView.reload data.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload particular cell as follow

```
 let cellIndexToRefresh = self.aryFeedIdsArray.indexOf("Your_UniqeID")! as Int
 self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: cellIndexToRefresh, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

Put inside the observer block where you have identified some update